# Caption font color with kable

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

Using kable() to render a simple table yields what seems to be the default pale font color for the table caption in the resulting html file. Is there a way to control the table (or figure) caption font color, size, etc?

````
    ---
    title: "test"
    output: 
    html_document: 
    theme: cosmo
    ---

    ```{r}
    library(knitr)
    tab.1 = table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)
    kable(tab.1, caption="Table 1: Caption Font Color")
    ```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aha! Customizing the CSS stylesheet does the trick.

```
caption {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Ani's answer: if you don't want to write the css stylesheet separately, you can just include another chunk after your YAML:

````
```{r results="asis"}
cat("
<style>
caption {
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.0em;
    }
</style>
")
```
````

Answer (score 4):

Now you can use a `css` code chunk directly, bypassing R. Adding `echo = FALSE` keeps it from being part of your output.

````
```{css, echo = FALSE}
caption {
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.0em;
    }
```
````