# How to get different custom CSS (font color) of kable headers with consecutive tables?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I want a blue caption then a red caption. I `cat` two HTML `<style>...</style>` sections, first blue second red, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53567045/6574038), but I get both red.

How to get a blue then a red caption?

````
---
output: html_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{r results="asis"}

cat("
<style>
caption {
      color: blue;
    }
</style>
")

knitr::kable(head(iris), 
             format="html",
             digits=4,
             row.names=FALSE,
             caption='Caption blue',
             escape=TRUE)|>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size=14) |>
  kableExtra::kable_paper(c('hover', 'condensed', 'responsive'), full_width=T) |>
  kableExtra::scroll_box(width="100%", height="200px") 
```


```{r results="asis"}

cat("
<style>
caption {
      color: red;
    }
</style>
")


knitr::kable(head(iris), 
             format="html",
             digits=4,
             row.names=FALSE,
             caption='Caption red',
             escape=TRUE) |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size=14) |>
  kableExtra::kable_paper(c('hover', 'condensed', 'responsive'), full_width=T) |>
  kableExtra::scroll_box(width="100%", height="200px")
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because second css overwrites the first css.

Better to do like this:

```
cat("
<style>
.blue-caption {
      color: blue;
    }

.red-caption {
      color: red;
    }
</style>
")
```

and then use like this:

```
caption='<span class=\"blue-caption\">Caption blue</span>',
caption='<span class=\"red-caption\">Caption red</span>',
```

Works?

Regards,
Noel

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Any clues why adding `font-size: .8em;` doesn't work?

Comment: It seems kableExtra overrides the font size. You can try with `extra_css` to add it:

`kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size=14, 
                            extra_css = "caption {font-size: .8em;}") |>`

Does this work?

Comment: My `kable_styling` has no `extra_css=`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specifying the CSS in each chunk, you can also give a special HTML class to each table and then gather all styling in a `css` chunk:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{css}
.mytable1 > caption {
    color: blue;
}
.mytable2 > caption {
    color: red;
}
```

```{r results="asis"}
knitr::kable(head(iris), 
             format="html",
             digits=4,
             row.names=FALSE,
             caption='Caption blue',
             escape=TRUE)|>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size=14, htmltable_class = "mytable1") |>
  kableExtra::kable_paper(c('hover', 'condensed', 'responsive'), full_width=T) |>
  kableExtra::scroll_box(width="100%", height="200px") 
```


```{r results="asis"}
knitr::kable(head(iris), 
             format="html",
             digits=4,
             row.names=FALSE,
             caption='Caption red',
             escape=TRUE) |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size=14, htmltable_class = "mytable2") |>
  kableExtra::kable_paper(c('hover', 'condensed', 'responsive'), full_width=T) |>
  kableExtra::scroll_box(width="100%", height="200px")
```
````

[image]

Alternatively we could insert inline css outside of a chunk.

```
<style>
.mytable1 > caption {
  color: blue;
}
.mytable2 > caption {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve the problem easier using [spin](https://deanattali.com/2015/03/24/knitrs-best-hidden-gem-spin/); we can create inline css (see edit) in the way we create text  there.

Comment: Any clues why adding `font-size: .8em;` doesn't work?

Comment: As said under the other answer, you need to remove `font_size = 14` which overrides your custom CSS