# Serif not working when bookdown fonts change in style.css

Tags: css, fonts, bookdown, gitbook

The option to toggle between sans-serif and serif using the `font-setting` button doesn't work when I change the fonts in style.CSS. Any suggestions?

This seems to happen when I change fonts for the main text, such as:

_output.yml

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
```

style.CSS

```
p {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

But not all text changes. For example, if you change just the font for lists, the button still works fine.

style.CSS

```
li {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

The button itself seems to work fine, toggling between the class 
`.font-family-1` = sans-serif and `.font-family-0` = serif

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Edited to make more reproducible. The issue can be reproduced using other CSSh  examples, such using: https://github.com/hebrewseniorlife/bookdownThemeEditor

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274501/r-markdown-changing-font-size-and-font-type-in-html-output

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I think what you are observing is the expected behavior of the fontsetting gitbook plugin.

> The button itself seems to work fine, toggling between the class .font-family-1 = sans-serif and .font-family-0 = serif

When you click on the button, the html root node of the book change class between `.font-family-1` and `.font-family-0`

If you want to change the default `font-family` used for the book, you can customize css to override the default which is

```css
.book.font-family-0 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
.book.font-family-1 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The button will change the class to the root not of class `.book` and apply the correct css to the all book.