# Blastula: Font size in R

Tags: r

Do you know, how to change the font size of emails that are written in r through blastula, I know how to change the font family but not the size.

Example:

email <- compose_email(font_family  =  "Montserrat",
body = md(c(
"Team, How would you plot the relationship between these 3 variables?",
plot_email)))

Answer (score 0):

As `blastula` makes use `R markdown` you can make use of markdown way to change the font size with HTML font tags `<font size = ''></font>`. It is covered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274501/r-markdown-changing-font-size-and-font-type-in-html-output#:%7E:text=You%20can%20change%20the%20font,output%20of%20the%20HTML%20output.).
Taking your example:

```
email <- compose_email(
  font_family = "Montserrat", 
  body = md(c( "<font size='6'> Team, How would you plot the relationship between these 3 variables?</font>", plot_email)))
```